# Intervention for gender dysphoria: Challenge the patient’s idea of gender roles and expectations?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, developmental-psychology, gender, transgender

According to the [DSM-5](https://repository.poltekkes-kaltim.ac.id/657/1/Diagnostic%20and%20statistical%20manual%20of%20mental%20disorders%20_%20DSM-5%20(%20PDFDrive.com%20).pdf), gender dysphoria is

> a marked incongruence between one’s experienced/expressed gender and assigned
> gender.

This might be something which arises out of the patient’s perception of gender roles as defined by society, i.e., girls should wear pink and play with dolls, while boys should wear blue and play with toy cars.

Would an intervention to help the patient question, challenge and cope with societal gender-based expectations regarding appearance and behavior help alleviate gender dysphoria?

Such an intervention could focus on the possibility of existing or identifying as a masculine woman or a feminine man. It could also include education on the fact that the concept of a [third gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender) is a possibility and is present in several cultures around the world. For example, [according to a research article from the American Indian Culture and Research Journal](https://doi.org/10.17953%2Faicr.35.4.x500172017344j30), Some traditional Diné Native Americans acknowledge a spectrum of four genders: feminine woman, masculine woman, feminine man, and masculine man.

I was unable to find research on this type of intervention and am looking for references to any relevant research.

---

### My Research

I have found a few relevant questions here but none that directly answers my question or links to relevant research.

[Conscious basis for gender identification](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9737/conscious-basis-for-gender-identification) – Here, a case is presented for an underlying biological mechanism for gender identification, but there is no mention of the effectiveness of expanding or relaxing the patient’s definitions/expectations of the two genders as an intervention against gender dysphoria.

[On what basis do professionals who recognize gender dysphoria support risky and permanent medical intervention for those seeking gender re-assignment?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/19795/on-what-basis-do-professionals-who-recognize-gender-dysphoria-support-risky-and) – Here, an “affirming approach” is presented as the best method to alleviate gender dysphoria. However, no explicit mention is made of trying to expand the patient’s definition and expectation of their gender.